# Javascript render number array to span elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to render the following series of numbers as below:

> 123456789**1**23456789**2**23456789**3**23456789**4**23456789**5**

```
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
...
<span>9</span>
<span class="bold">1</span>
<span>2</span>
...
```

What is the best way considering that;

1.The total character length can be dynamic. For now we can consider it as above example.

2.I want some of the characters to be in bold as shown.

What is the best way to implement the same?

I was planning to create a static array with individual characters as:

```
1234567891234567892234567893234567894234567895
```

Then iterate and render them using jQuery.

PS: The sequence of numbers appearing and the boldness would always be the same even though the total length can change. (I think it is max 80 chars.)

Comment: You forgot to mention what pattern you use to determine which ones should be bold.  Is it every tenth element should be bold?

Comment: `1` how you are going to recognise bold `1` from your string? is it contain any tag there?

Comment: "I was planning to create a static array with individual characters as 1234567891234567892234567893234567894234567895 Then iterate & render them using jQuery" Seems like you already know what to do?

Comment: I think that pattern is based on 10n+10

Comment: Your example above doesn't follow the 10n+10 pattern

Answer (score 2):

```js
var n='1234567891234567892234567893234567894234567895';
$.each(n.split(''),function(key,value){
  $("#NU").append($('<span/>',{text:value, class:((!(key%9)&key>0)?"bold":"")}));
});
```

```css
.bold{color:blue;font-weight:bold}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="NU"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the array of numbers using `forEach` and use `append` to add the span recursively into the `result` div.

Also, you can check if the `index` is divisible by `10`, to add the `bold` condition.

```js
var num = "1234567891234567892234567893234567894234567895".split('');



num.forEach((n, i) => {
  if ((i + 1) % 10 === 0) {
    $('#result').append(`<span class='bold'>${n}</span>`);
  } else {
    $('#result').append(`<span>${n}</span>`);

  }
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: It's a bit rude to down vote an answer which is perfectly fine without an explanation :/

Answer (score 0):

you can create two strings, the first one with all the numbers that you want, the second with all bold numbers and do a loop on the all numbers string and check if the number is on the other if is it add the bold tag ig isn't just add the number

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = '1234567891234567892234567893234567894234567895';

$(document.body).append($.map(test.split(''), function(element, index){
  var $span = $('<span>').text(element);
  
  if (!((index + 1) % 10)) $span.addClass('bold');
  
  return $span;
}));
```

```css
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: dear friend,  dont   last char(5) to "bold"

Comment: The question stated the pattern is 10n+10, but the example doesn't match that.  I'm waiting on a follow up in the comments. @FarhadBagherlo